# populating text box data from the database based on static drop down selected

Tags: php, html, mysql

i want to fill up the text boxes with the data from the database vales. But at the same time it should display the values according to the static drop down value selected. I am not getting how to achieve this. Here is my code

```
<form name="form1" action="submit.php" method="post">
  <tr bgcolor="#00BFFF">
    <td><strong>Month</strong></td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
    <select name="month"><option value="january">January</option>
    <option value="february">February</option>
    <option value="march">March</option>
    <option value="april">April</option>
    <option value="may">May</option>
    <option value="june">June</option>
    <option value="july">July</option>
    <option value="august">August</option>
    <option value="september">September</option>
    <option value="october">October</option>
    <option value="november">November</option>
    <option value="december">December</option>
    </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="text" name="day1" id="day1" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="day2" id="day2" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="day3" id="day3" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="day4" id="day4" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="day5" id="day5" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="day6" id="day6" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="day7" id="day7" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="day8" id="day8" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="day9" id="day9" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="day10" id="day10" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="day11" id="day11" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="day12" id="day12" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="day13" id="day13" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="day14" id="day14" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="day15" id="day15" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="day16" id="jan16" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="day17" id="day17" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="day18" id="day18" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="day19" id="day19" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="day20" id="day20" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="day21" id="day21" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="day22" id="day22" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="day23" id="day23" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="day24" id="day24" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="day25" id="day25" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="day26" id="day26" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="day27" id="day27" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="day28" id="day28" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="day29" id="day29" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="day30" id="day30" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="day31" id="day31" style="width:87%;" /></td>
    <input type="hidden" name="pid" value="<?php echo $product_id ?>"/>
  </tr>
  <tr><td colspan="32" align="center"><input type="submit" value="SUBMIT DATA" name="submit" style="font-size:18px; font-weight:bold;"  /></td></tr>

  </form>
</table>
```

In this page, it should populate the text box values fetching from the database according to the month selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use javascript to make an XmlHttpRequest for the data you require, or embed all of the data you require in the page when it is served and use javascript to selectively show / hide bits.

Comment: can you please share any tutorial for this, as i am not good at javascript.

Comment: It's a rather broad subject user2669924. 
First learn about Javascript if not already done, next read about AJAX (retrieving data asynchronously by making XmlHttpRequests with Javascript), then read about JQuery as it nicely demonstrates DOM manipulation with Javascript (changing HTML elements after the user has loaded the page).